# Export default failed in JSX with babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I'm trying to rendering a Footer class in `accounts.js`. (Actually the extension should be .jsx, while it won't solve the problem here I think.)

First I import the Footer in accounts.jsx:

```
import React from "react";

import {Footer} from "../utils/footer.js";

import {SEEMIKO_LOGO} from "./const.js";

export default React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row login-div">
              <div className="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-3"
                   style={{marginTop: '2vw'}}>
                <img src={SEEMIKO_LOGO}/>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-offset-6">
                {this.props.children}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Then I define `footer.js` below:

```
import React from "react";

// var Footer = React.createClass({
export default React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <footer className="footer">
          <div className="container">
            <p className="copyright" style={{color: "black"}}>
              C 西米糕 Seemiko Inc. 2014 - Current. 浙XXXXX
            </p>
            <ul className="footer-links">
              <li>
                <a href="#">用户反馈</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">使用帮助</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">关于我们</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </footer>
    );
  }
})

// works
// export {Footer};
```

The weird thing is if I use `export default` in footer.js, it will failed. But once I switch to `var Footer` with `export Footer`, all set. Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a default export you also need to use a default import:

```
import Footer from '...';
```

Comment: I have changed `import {Footer} from "../utils/footer.js";` in `accounts.js` into `import Footer from "../utils/footer.js";`, which solves this problem indeed. Thank you!